# Recursive hierarchical traversal in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, recursion

Using MSSQL, I am trying to traverse through a table with parent child relationship. I need my result set so that I get all elements in a proper indented manner, till the last leaf, like shown below.

A parent item 36 has 2 children 17 and 18. Each of those children 17 and 18 have one more children to them 26, 42 respectively

```
 36 - 17 
 17 - 26 
 36 - 18 
 18 - 42
```

But my recursion is working OK in terms of the data traversal, but order wise, it is failing. My recursive query gives me the following output

```
36 - 17 
36 - 18 
17 - 26 
18 - 42
```

It brings all levels at once, stores them in a record, then traverses through each of the children of those levels.

Oracle's "connect by prior" seems to be working fine, but, MSSQL is not.  I am pasting a sample of what I am using

```
WITH SRC (Level, PARITEMID, CHIITEMID) AS 
  (
    SELECT 
        0 as Level,
        PI.pitem_id as PARITEMID,
        CI.pitem_id as CHIITEMID
  FROM PI, CI JOIN <Condition> where PI.PITEM_ID =

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
        Level + 1,
        PI1.pitem_id as PARITEMID,
        CI1.pitem_id AS CHIITEMID
       FROM PI1, CI1 JOIN <Condition>
)
Select * from SRC
```

Is there something I need to do on the SRC I obtain by ordering it, or is there fundamentally something wrong with the recursion itself?

Comment: As usual, if you need a certain order of the final result set you must specify `ORDER BY`. Without `ORDER BY` clause the rows in the result set may be returned in any order.

Comment: It is a parent child relationship. There is no order that I can specify upfront. Can you pls suggest a workable ORDER by which I can get each hierarchy till the leaf

Comment: If you provide some sample data (a dozen rows should be enough), preferably in the form of `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements, and your expected result of the query, you will likely get a good answer pretty fast. It may also help if you add a tag with the version of SQL Server that you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasn't clear on your field names so I assumed the following:

cItem_ID - Child ID
pItem_ID - Parent ID
item_Title - Item name/Description

Also, not clear on the Sequence, So I assumed Item_Title (alphabetical).  However, you can use any field available. (see the the "10000+Row_Number()" lines)

I should note, cteR1, and cteR2 are not necessary.  I do like the range keys, they server many purposes.  If you do remove them, just set the final Order By to `Order By A.Seq`

```
Declare @MyTable table (pItem_ID int,cItem_ID int,item_Title varchar(50))
Insert into @MyTable values 
 (null,36,'Item 36')
,(36,17,'Item 17')
,(17,26,'Item 26')
,(36,18,'Item 18')
,(18,42,'Item 42')


Declare @Top    int         = null      --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 7 
Declare @Nest   varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by item_Title) as varchar(500))
            ,cItem_ID
            ,pItem_ID
            ,Lvl=1
            ,item_Title 
      From   @MyTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(pItem_ID,-1) else cItem_ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.item_Title)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.cItem_ID
            ,r.pItem_ID
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.item_Title 
      From   @MyTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.pItem_ID = p.cItem_ID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.cItem_ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.cItem_ID )
Select A.R1  
      ,B.R2
      ,A.cItem_ID
      ,A.pItem_ID
      ,A.Lvl
      ,item_Title = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.item_Title
 From cteR1 A
 Join cteR2 B on A.cItem_ID=B.cItem_ID
 Order By A.R1
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a nice way of keeping track of the order and sorting based in that. It worked

Comment: @Srikanth Happy it helped.